# How to add attribute to Text field in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have to add attribute to some text filed and number fields in my Sencha touch form. there I didn't find any config option, that we can set attribute to these fields/controls.

Is there any option provided by Sencha Touch to add attributes to these controls?

like below html code/cotrols I need to set attribute in my sencha touch controls. if is there any way, please suggest me. your help will be valuable for me.

This is HTML code. I want to set my Sencha filed like this attribute added in html code. here you can see `data-openpay-card` is added as attribute

```
<html>
<label>Nombre del titular</label><input type="text" name="holder" placeholder="Como aparece en la tarjeta" autocomplete="off" data-openpay-card="holder_name"></input>
<label>Número de tarjeta</label><input type="text" name="card" autocomplete="off" data-openpay-card="card_number"></div <div class="sctn-col half l"><input type="text" name="month" placeholder="Mes" data-openpay-card="expiration_month"></div>
<div class="sctn-col half l"><input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Año" data-openpay-card="expiration_year"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: You want to add attribute for component OR its dom ?

Comment: yes I want to add attributes for its DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vikas In ExtJS, they have inputAttrTpl config. Using this its very easy to define the attributes directly to the input element of the textfield component.

But in Sencha Touch this config is not present for the text field. What you need to do is -

1. Listen to the painted event
2. In this event using the textfield element that is coming as a parameter, you can find the corresponding input element by doing a query.
3. then set the attribute using set method

Pleae refer following fiddle -

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kvu

Answer (score 2):

You can set attributes like below:-

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    listeners: {
        painted: function (el, eOpts) {
            el.dom.querySelector('input').setAttribute('data-openpay-card', 'your-value');
        }
    }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kvn)

Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.